# Network unreachable inside docker container without --net=host parameter

Tags: networking, docker, iptables

**Problem**: there is no internet connection in the docker container.

**Symptoms**: ping `8.8.8.8` doesn't work. Wireshark from host system gives back:

```
 19 10.866212113   172.17.0.2 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0009, seq=0/0, ttl=64
 20 11.867231972   172.17.0.2 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0009, seq=1/256, ttl=64
 21 12.868331353   172.17.0.2 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0009, seq=2/512, ttl=64
 22 13.869400083   172.17.0.2 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0009, seq=3/768, ttl=64
```

**But**! If container was started with `--net=host` internet would work perfectly.

What I've tried so far:

- [altering DNS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com)
- adding `--ip-masq=true` to `/etc/default/docker` (with restart off)
- enabling everything related to masquerade / ip_forward
- altering default route
- everything suggested [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12926)

Host config:

```
$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.4.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1.3001
default         10.3.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno2
10.3.2.0      *               255.255.254.0   U     100    0        0 eno2
10.4.2.0      *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eno1.3001
nerv8.i         10.3.2.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eno2
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

`sudo iptables -L`, `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, `ifconfig`, `iptables -t nat -L -nv`

Everything is fine, forwarding is also enabled:

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward 
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: What's the version of docker (`docker --version`), the underlying host (`uname -a`), the name of the Dockerimage you are using, and the command you use to run the container?

Comment: $ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
$ uname -a
Linux 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP

16.04

Answer (score 5):

This is the not full answer you are looking for. But I would like to give some explanation on why the internet is working

> If container was started with --net=host internet would work
>   perfectly.

**Docker by default supports three networks**. **In this mode(HOST) container will share the host’s network stack and all interfaces from the host will be available to the container**. The container’s host name will match the hostname on the host system

```
# docker run -it --net=host ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:/# hostname
labadmin-VirtualBox
Even the IP configuration is same as the host system's IP configuration
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:/# ip addr | grep -A 2 eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b5:82:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: lxcbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:/# exit
exit
```

**HOST SYSTEM IP CONFIGURATION**

```
# ip addr | grep -A 2 eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b5:82:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: lxcbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
```

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083328/what-is-the-use-of-host-and-none-network-in-docker/43873743#43873743) for more information about docker networking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run "sudo ifconfig" and see if the range of IPs for your internet connection (typically wlan0) is colliding with the range for docker0 interface 172.17.0.0 ?

I had this issue with my office network (while it was working fine at home) that it ran on 172.17.0.X and Docker tried to pick exactly that range.

This might be of help: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/

I ended up creating my own bridge network for Docker.

Answer (score -1):

Check that `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` (not `net.ipv4.ip_forward`) is set to `1`, if not, turn it on:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding

net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0

$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding

net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Plus I had to start the container with the "--privileged" option or I would get a "Read-only file system" message.