# Usecase for running docker container with none network type

Tags: docker, networking

I know docker have none network type in which no IP address is assigned to container and no network interfaces is created except loopback interface.

I want to know any usecase where we can use the none network type, I mean in which scenario do we need to run a container without IP or interfaces.

I had referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083328/what-is-the-use-of-host-and-none-network-in-docker) but it didn't answer the exact usecase where we can use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @VonC I got an idea from your answer.

It seems docker `none` network type is used by other network plugins like calico, weave, etc to provide its own network stack.

Docker networking model is based on CNM (Container Network Model) while there is another model called CNI (Container Network Interface) which is used by network pulgins like calico, weave, etc.

I guess these network plugins (one which uses CNI model) uses the `none` network type so that a container got created with no networking on top of which these CNI plugins provides its own networking.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/blob/master/SPEC.md, that is possible, yes.

Answer (score 3):

First, as mentioned in [weaveworks/weave issue 1394](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/1394):

> the meaning of `--net=none` is not clear. It could mean "no networking at all" (in which case weave networking should be disabled too), or "no Docker networking" (which is the interpretation I am choosing here).

That is what the [wave network](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave) is doing:

> We create a network namespace with `--net=none`, inject the weave interface and then start the actual container.
>   We also run a default gateway within the weave network that has external connectivity.
>
> **The reason we are doing this is that services tend to bind to the wrong interface. It's important to have a single interface that is created before the container is started**.

You find a similar usecase with **[Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v1.6/reference/without-docker-networking/installation)**;

> This tutorial describes how to set up a Calico cluster in a Docker environment **without Docker networking (i.e. `–net=none`)**.
>
> With this option, Docker creates a container with its own network stack, but not to take any steps to configure its network.
>   Rather than have Docker configure the network, in this tutorial we use the `calicoctl` command line tool to add a container into a Calico network: adding the required interface and routes in to the container, and configuring Calico with the correct endpoint information.