# Docker Bridge Network DNS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-network

I've two containers running on the default docker bridge network. The daemon assign them a "casual" ip on a specific range.

```
network_mode: bridge -> 172.17.0.X
```

How can I reach each other via some alias or name?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take following containers running with base image Ubuntu:16.04:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2461f410228b        ubuntu:16.04        "/bin/bash"         20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes                           competent_shockley
6da9d8196637        ubuntu:16.04        "/bin/bash"         21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes                           hungry_mccarthy
```

**Default networks by Docker**, to know more about the default networks refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083328/what-is-the-use-of-host-and-none-network-in-docker/43873743#43873743):

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
f83800356529        bridge              bridge              local
8169b2246500        host                host                local
b61e4f39c0ec        none                null                local
```

Let's find out the containers IP address using `docker inspect`:

```
$ docker inspect 2461f410228b | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",


$ docker inspect 6da9d8196637 | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
```

By default, **containers launched in BRIDGE network will be able to access other containers launched in same network**.

```
root@2461f410228b:/# ping 172.18.0.2
PING 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
```

As you are looking for reaching the other container using name/alias, add the target container information in the file /etc/hosts to resolve the DNS:

```
root@2461f410228b:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.3      2461f410228b
172.18.0.2      docker2
```

Now try to reach target container using the hostname:

```
root@2461f410228b:/# ping docker2
PING docker2 (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from docker2 (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
```

I believe this may help to some extent.

Comment: My final aim is to connect a phpmyadmin container to a mariadb container, avoiding link in composer. What should i use as DNS in "Server" input?

Comment: Didn't get "What should i use as DNS in "Server" input". Can you elaborate this? What "Server" you are talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

I was running a Spring Boot jar in one Docker container and wanted to connect to an Oracle database running in another. In the Spring application.properties file I referenced the database url as

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521/xepdb1
```

In my Windows C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file I resolved 'oracle' as the localhost IP so I could run as Java application from Eclipse...

```
127.0.0.1 oracle
```

From the docker inspect command I was able to determine the IP address of the Oracle container as 172.17.0.2.

When I ran my Spring Boot container I ran it with the --add-host switch to resolve 'oracle' as the database container's IP address...

```
docker run --add-host=oracle:172.17.0.2 -p 9090:8080 -dit --name <name> <image>
```

In my Jenkins post build batch commands I capture the IP of the running database container and pass it to the app container on startup...

```
for /F %%x in ('docker inspect -f "{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" oracle-xe') do set ip=%%x
docker run --add-host=oracle:%ip% -p 9090:8080 -dit --name demo demo
```