# What's the different between host mode and bridge mode?

Tags: linux, docker, centos

When I use the `host mode` to run mycontainer, it doesn't work,but the `bridge mode` works.I'd like to ask what's the different between the two modes?

Run with `host mode`:
`docker run  --name=zhiwenyi --net=host -d [image]`

Run with `bridge mode`:`docker run --name=zhiwenyi -d -p 35229:35229 [image]`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /data/log/upload
COPY target/upload_V6_20220722.jar upload.jar
EXPOSE 35229
RUN bash -c "touch /upload.jar"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx512m","-Xms512m","-jar","-Duser.timezone=GMT+08","-Dfile.encoding=utf-8","upload.jar"]
```

In `bridge mode`, I send a `post request` to `myip:35229/path` ,it works well.

In `host mode`, the same request ,it shows me `connection time out`.

**Supply**:

1. **OS**:`centos 7.9`
2. **Docker**:`20.10.17`

Comment: Related: [What does --net=host option in Docker command really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316376/what-does-net-host-option-in-docker-command-really-do); [What is the use of Docker 'host' and 'none' Networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083328/what-is-the-use-of-docker-host-and-none-networks)

Comment: You should not normally need `--net=host`, so if your second form works (either without a `--net` option at all, or `--net=something-you-created`) I'd use that without worrying about it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,I've learnd the two modes. General speaking, the programe can work in the two ways above.But it only works in `bridge mode`,what's wrong with `host mode`?

Comment: It disables Docker's core networking features; so you can't hide or remap a container port on the host, and you can't communicate between containers using container names as host names

Comment: For example using `nginx`: 1. `docker run --name=nginx1 -d -p 80:80 nginx`  2. `docker run --name=nginx2 --net=host nginx`. I could have  access  the container on `ip:80`. But I can't acess the container with host mode,why?

Answer (score 0):

**If you use host mode it disables the container's network namespace.**

> A bridge network in the context of Docker employs a software bridge to
> provide isolation from containers that are not linked to that bridge
> network while enabling communication between containers that are
> connected to the same bridge network.

> The network stack of a container that uses the host network driver is
> not separated from the Docker host. For instance, if you utilize host
> networking and run a container that binds to port 80, the application
> for the container will be accessible on port 80 on the host's IP
> address.